# To convert microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage into MimeMessage

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am working with Exchange Web Service in Java. I already have some code implemented that deal with MimeMessage. Now we are thinking to work with Exchange Web Service.

Is there any way to convert microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage into MimeMessage ??

Comment: hello, already have this anwser?

Answer (score 0):

At the client no, if the Item you working with exists in the Exchange Store then you can just load the MIMEContent eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh545614(v=exchg.140).aspx. (at that point if no MimeContent exists for the Item the Exchange store will do an on the fly conversion).

Cheers
Glen